# Need to add direct checkout instead of adding to the cart in opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: opencart, checkout

Orignal code from opencart:-

```
var cart = {
    'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('reset');
            },
            success: function(json) {
                $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

                if (json['redirect']) {
                    location = json['redirect'];
                }

                if (json['success']) {
$('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
                    }, 100);

                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
```

I tried to edit these way but it had no effect on the front end everything was same
check below i tried replacing the code here:-

```
    var cart = {
        'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

                    if (json['redirect']) {
                        location = json['redirect'];
                    }
           //here i replaced the code
                    if (json['success']) {
                    window.location='index.php?route=checkout/checkout';
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
```

can anyone kindly help me out with these opencart 2.3.0.2 problem..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, I'm on 2.3.0.2 and have multiple stores using this in the Success statement to redirect to the cart page after clicking add to cart.

```
  window.location.href = "index.php?route=checkout/cart";
```

Obviously you'd want to change it to:

```
  window.location.href = "index.php?route=checkout/checkout";
```

Good luck!

Comment: hey Alexander, where do i have to replace that code on which page??

Comment: the page is in your catalog/view/theme/(theme name)/product/product.tpl

You'll want to look at your add to cart success function (it may be different depending on your theme), which is almost always on the bottom of the page. You can also post the contents of your javascript functions on here and I can assist further.

Comment: hey Alexander, thanks i did that it works but there still a problem it only works when iam on the product page, and it does not work when iam on the home screen or at the list of products.
kindly help me with that also..

Comment: Hey Salman,

No problem at all, it's pretty straight forward now that you've done it on the product.tpl page. Can you tell me which modules you are using to display those products on those pages? Featured? Carousel? I have to know that first.

Comment: Ok, so on the featured product module, in the /catalog/view/theme/(themename)/extensions/module/featured.tpl you would want to do the same thing as you did on the product.tpl

If this works out for you, could you vote this up or mark it as the answer? I'm still limited on how much I can help others with my low score, since I just started. Thanks!

Comment: well thanks your solution it helped me, still i need more help, i mean how to add delay before these code gets executed.."window.location='index.php?route=checkout/checkout';" bcoz sometime the codes gets executed first and the cart remain's empty.

Comment: I was going to mention that!!!

Change your URL to    window.location.href = "index.php?route=checkout/checkout", 5000); there 5 is 5 milliseconds (so you'd want 1,000 for 1 second, 2,000 for 2 seconds,etc).

It's a bit dirty but it should work, ill test it as well within the next hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

replace the redirect function where you already changed with the code below

```
window.location='index.php?route=checkout/checkout';
```

with this code, this will redirect to your checkout.

```
location.href='index.php?route=checkout/checkout';
```

Comment: Please format your code. Also, please let the OP know the difference between the statements you have mentioned in your answer which will help them understand the issue.